# react поместить ячейку таблицы в ряд в конце цикла

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно помещать в конце каждого цикла newElement в row так, чтобы функция возвращала ряд таблицы с несколькими ячейками

```
var NewRow = () => {
      var row = <tr></tr>;
      for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var newElement = <td>{tableRow[properties[i]]}</td>;
    }
    return row;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не особо вникая в ваши исходные структуры данных, может быть примерно так:

```
const getSeq  = to => [...Array(to.length)].map((_, i) => i);

const renderRow = row => <tr>{getSeq(arr.length).map(i =>
                            <td>{tableRow[properties[i]]}</td>)}
                         </tr>;
```

Но, возможно, нужно что-то вроде:

```
<table>
    <tbody>{tableRows.map(row =>
        <tr>{row.properties.map(cell =>
            <td>{cell}</td>)}
        </tr>}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!